# Is there a way to upload a locally developed WordPress website to Microsoft Azure App Service?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure-web-app-service

I recently developed a WordPress website and I want to host it on Azure App Service

I uploaded the site files via ftp and I also uploaded the database but I can't seem to connect to the database. I keep getting the error in database connection message

Comment: Did you change the database connection code/paremeters to connect to the new database. its unlikely the same as when it ran elsewhere

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Check the connection details in `wp-config.php` file.